# Strange loop behavior in Python

Tags: python

The code:

```
total = 0

for number in xrange(10000):
    divisors = 0
    divisors2 = 0

    for dividend in xrange(1, number/2):
        if number % dividend == 0:
            divisors = divisors + dividend

    for dividend2 in xrange(1, divisors/2):
        if divisors % dividend2 == 0:
            divisors2 = divisors2 + dividend2

    if number == divisors2:
        total = total + number + divisors

print total
```

The code is supposed to generate amicable numbers(i.e. number that total number of divisors less than itself equal another number that's total number of divisors equal the original number, see [Project Euler, problem 21](http://projecteuler.net/problem=21)) under 10,000 and add them as it finds them. It's generating 48, which is way too low.

The program ran a lot faster than I expected it to: I'm running through a lot of numbers and I know for a fact that this isn't a very fast way to get the proper divisors, so I suspected something was up with the loop, either that Python was just stopping unexpectedly, or was running the loops out of order. If I put a command to print divisors before the beginning of the next loop, it goes on forever, and tends to print long lines of the same number. Something strange is definitely going on here. I googled "strange loop behavior", and searched here, to no avail. I also checked [here].[2](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html)

What's going on and what should I do about it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should `divisors` and `divisors2` be numbers or sequences?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrangeLoop.html

Comment: They are totals. Just regular old ints.

Comment: It might be helpful to wait until the end to sum all the amicable numbers. That way you can examine (`print`) that list and see what sort of numbers you are getting.

Comment: Also, Problem 21 doesn't ask for the total *number* of amicable numbers, it asks for the *sum* of all amicable numbers (under 10000).

Comment: Yes, I know it asks for the sum. I reread my post and fixed some confusing language. I put a print number, divisor line after line 16, to check. Gives 0 0 and 24 24. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xrange(1, n)
```

gives you numbers from `1 ... n-1`.  To get numbers from `1 ... n`, you will need to do `xrange(1, n+1)`.  You make this mistake twice in your code.

You are also not checking for the condition about `a != b` in the original problem.

Comment: Fixed the problem. Thought I had fixed it already. Than you. Why should I check for that condition?

Comment: Let's take 28.  The sum of its factors (1, 2, 4, 7, 14) is 28.  The sum of the factors of the result is of course 28 again.  But (28, 28) is not an amicable pair because the two numbers must be different.  In other words, you need to make sure `number` and `divisors` are not equal, but `number` and `divisors2` are equal.

Comment: Also, by adding `number + divisors` to the `total`, you are double counting.  You will add this pair again when `number` and `divisors` swap values in a next iteration of the loop (unless `number == divisors`, but those cases need to be not counted at all anyway).  You can change that part of the code to just `total = total + number`.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't sure. The question was vague. I anticipated the problem and it's an easy fix: total \ 2.

Answer (score 3):

Few issues here:

It should be

```
total = total + number
```

And, range(1,x) runs only till x-1. So, you need to specify range(1, n/2 + 1)

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm's broken. Let's take the amicable number given in the example, 284, and run it through your code:

```
number = 284
divisors = divisors2 = 0

for dividend in range(1, number/2): #goes through all the numbers (1, 2, ..., 141)
    if not number % dividend: divisors += dividend 

#divisors = 78

for dividend2 in range(1, divisors/2): #goes through all the numbers (1, 2, ..., 38)
    if not divisors % dividend2: divisors2 += dividend2

#divisors2 = 51

if number == divisors2:
    #number != divisors2, because 284 != 51
    #the amicable number never gets added to your sum
```

Comment: Very comprehensive. Thank you very much.